# How to do BNF matching with a BNF parser?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, bnf

I am using https://github.com/sylvainhalle/Bullwinkle/, a BNF parser. But it can only recognize a BNF pattern for single-whole-sentence, how to find BNF matches in a paragraph?
I am trying to recognize certain commands in human's speaking. For a BNF example:

```
<S>: <lightcmd>;
<lightcmd>: <do> <obj> | <do> <a> <obj>;
<do>: turn on | turn off;
<a>: a | an | the;
<obj>: light;
```

I can parse the right command from speaking "turn on the light", but I can't parse it from "please turn on the light".

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing more clearly.  But I think you are using the wrong tool for the task you are trying to do.  Parsing and pattern matching are different problems.

Comment: Ok, I think I should try regular expression tool to do it. But is regular expression a subset of BNF?

Comment: From a certain perspective, yes ... but that doesn't make parsers the right tool for pattern matching.   Perhaps if you explained what you are actually trying to do we could give you some advice.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to parse "please turn on the light" against that grammar, the parser will attempt to parse the entire utterance ... because that is what parsers do.  But what you want is to match part of the utterance.

Now you *could* deal with this something like the following:

```
<S>: <words> <lightcmd> <words>;
<lightcmd>: <do> <obj> | <do> <a> <obj>;
<do>: turn on | turn off;
<a>: a | an | the;
<obj>: light;
<words>: <word> | <words> <word>
<word>: // one or more letters
```

but you start getting into problems with ambiguity.

I think that a better idea would be to try to parse sub-sequences of the word stream.  So if the user says

```
please turn on a light and make a cup of tea
```

you attempt to parse starting with "please".  Then when that fails you try starting with "turn".  Then when you reach "light" you ignore the rest of the words.

I don't know if Bullwinkle can be used like that.  If not, look for alternative parser generators.

---

However, it should also be noted that a grammar as simple as this can also be written as a regular expression where the words are treated as the base symbols.  You would only need a simple regular expression engine to handle this.  (If this grammar is typical, you only need grouping and alternation.  It should only be a couple of hours work to implement this from scratch.)

Comment: Thanks for your explain. Although I have no idea of how to write the arbitrary matcher <word> due to poor documentation of Bullwinkle, and in fact I am dealing with Chinese word stream (something Unicode arbitrary matcher?). As you say, I could try to parse sub-sequences, for [begin-end] in {[0,0], ... , [0,n], [1,1], ... , [1,n], ..., [n,n]}, this is of O(n^2) * O(parsing), I wonder if it take too much complexity than a pattern matcher?

Comment: Well, it depends on the context.  But, for example, it is O(1) to find the first instance of "turn" in a sequence of words.

Comment: Ok, by getting the first-word-list of the patterns (not sure if Bullwinkle provides the function), filter the occurrences of the first-words (O(1)?), the complexity can then be reduced to O(1) * O(n) * O(parsing).